# Best way to handle a bidding site in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, credit-card

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to make a site similar to ebay (users can put up listings and others can bid on those listings).  I was wondering what the best possible way to handle fund transfers from one user to another.  Would PayPal be the best solution or are there any other services that can do it better with no fees or without a percentage cut out of each transaction?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the buyer will first transfert the money to your account, then you'll send this money to the seller after taking a cut. Of course, you can accept paypal or any other payment gateway. See [active_merchant](http://activemerchant.org) for further information.